# IP already in use via Docker Compose file error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker-compose and trying to create the following.
My network at home is a 192.168.1.0/24 network. I have a raspberry pi with docker on it installed with IP 192.168.1.50

I want to create 2 containers as with PiHole and Unbound. I want to reach Pihole via 192.168.1.200 address. And I have created also a bridge for the communication between PiHole and Adguard. When I start the docker compose file I get an error :

```
reating network "dockerfiles_mvltest" with driver "macvlan"
Creating network "dockerfiles_brdtest" with driver "bridge"
Creating pihole  ... error
Creating unbound ... 

Creating unbound ... done

ERROR: for pihole  Cannot start service pihole: Address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

This is how the docker-compose.yaml file looks like :

```
version: '3'

services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
#     cap_add: # Uncomment if you want to use Pi-Hole for DHCP
#       - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
      - 53/tcp
      - 53/udp
#       - 67/udp # Uncomment if you want to use Pi-Hole for DHCP
      - 80/tcp
    environment:
      - FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4=192.168.1.200
      - WEBPASSWORD=Welkom123
      - PIHOLE_DNS_=10.1.0.2
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
      - DNSMASQ_USER=root
      - DNSMASQ_LISTENING=local
    volumes:
      - ./pihole/data:/etc/pihole:rw
      - ./pihole/dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d/:rw
    networks:
      mvltest:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.200
      brdtest:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.0.1
    restart: always
  unbound:
    container_name: unbound
    image: mvance/unbound:latest
    ports:
      - 53/tcp
      - 53/udp
    networks:
      brdtest:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.0.2
    restart: always

networks:
  mvltest:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: ens33
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.1.254
  brdtest:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.1.0.0/30
```

What am I doing wrong?

I was hoping that this construction is going to work. I found this example on youtube.

Comment: Try a different IP address for Pihole.  That is what I would do here.

Comment: Careful: it doesn't say IP address. It says address. This is an error from the *bind* operation, signaling that an IP address + port + protocol combination is already in use. Do check that.